# Why my query is slow?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT "Series".*
  ,"SeriesTranslations"."id" AS "SeriesTranslations.id"
  ,"SeriesTranslations"."title" AS "SeriesTranslations.title"
  ,"SeriesTranslations"."subtitle" AS "SeriesTranslations.subtitle"
  ,"SeriesTranslations"."slug" AS "SeriesTranslations.slug"
  ,"SeriesTranslations"."language" AS "SeriesTranslations.language"
  ,"SeriesTranslations"."seoTitle" AS "SeriesTranslations.seoTitle"
  ,"SeriesTranslations"."seoDescription" AS "SeriesTranslations.seoDescription"
  ,"Posts"."id" AS "Posts.id"
  ,"Posts"."type" AS "Posts.type"
  ,"Posts"."contentDuration" AS "Posts.contentDuration"
  ,"Posts"."publishDate" AS "Posts.publishDate"
  ,"Posts"."publishedAt" AS "Posts.publishedAt"
  ,"Posts"."thumbnailUrl" AS "Posts.thumbnailUrl"
  ,"Posts"."imageUrl" AS "Posts.imageUrl"
  ,"Posts"."media" AS "Posts.media"
  ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."id" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.id"
  ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."slug" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.slug"
  ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."title" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.title"
  ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."subtitle" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.subtitle"
  ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."language" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.language"
FROM (
  SELECT "Series"."id"
    ,"Series"."thumbnailUrl"
    ,"Series"."imageUrl"
    ,"Series"."coverUrl"
  FROM "Series" AS "Series"
  WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM "SeriesTranslations" AS t
      WHERE t.LANGUAGE IN ('en-us')
        AND t.slug = 'in-residence-architecture-design-video-series'
        AND t."SeriesId" = "Series"."id" LIMIT 1
      ) LIMIT 1
  ) AS "Series"
INNER JOIN "SeriesTranslations" AS "SeriesTranslations" ON "Series"."id" = "SeriesTranslations"."SeriesId"
  AND "SeriesTranslations"."language" IN ('en-us')
LEFT JOIN "Posts" AS "Posts" ON "Series"."id" = "Posts"."SeriesId"
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM "PostTranslations" AS pt
    WHERE pt.LANGUAGE IN ('en-us')
      AND pt."PostId" = "Posts"."id" LIMIT 1
    )
LEFT JOIN "PostTranslations" AS "Posts.PostTranslations" ON "Posts"."id" = "Posts.PostTranslations"."PostId"
  AND "Posts.PostTranslations"."language" IN ('en-us')
ORDER BY "Posts"."publishDate" DESC;
```

It loads data from 4 tables "Series", "SeriesTranslations", "Posts" and "PostsTranslations". I retrieves single "Series" based on "SeriesTranslations" slug and also all "Posts" that belong to this series with their translations.

This query takes ~1.5 sec when series is returned with 14 posts (TOTAL 14 rows are returned from query). In DB there are just few series (no more than 5), each one has 2 translations. However there are many posts in DB - around 2000 and each one has 2 translations so around 4k PostTranslations...

---

Here is EXPLAIN result

[image]

I have unique indexes on "slug", "language" in "SeriesTranslations" and "PostTranslations" and also I have forign keys on "Posts"."SeriesId", "SeriesTranslations"."SeriesId" and "PostTranslations"."PostId"

---

EXPLAIN here http://explain.depesz.com/s/fhm

---

I simplified query as suggested: (removed one subquery and moved conditions to inner join) - however query is still slow...

```
SELECT "Series"."id"
    ,"Series"."thumbnailUrl"
    ,"Series"."imageUrl"
    ,"Series"."coverUrl"
    ,"SeriesTranslations"."id" AS "SeriesTranslations.id"
    ,"SeriesTranslations"."title" AS "SeriesTranslations.title"
    ,"SeriesTranslations"."subtitle" AS "SeriesTranslations.subtitle"
    ,"SeriesTranslations"."slug" AS "SeriesTranslations.slug"
    ,"SeriesTranslations"."language" AS "SeriesTranslations.language"
    ,"SeriesTranslations"."seoTitle" AS "SeriesTranslations.seoTitle"
    ,"SeriesTranslations"."seoDescription" AS "SeriesTranslations.seoDescription"
    ,"Posts"."id" AS "Posts.id"
    ,"Posts"."type" AS "Posts.type"
    ,"Posts"."contentDuration" AS "Posts.contentDuration"
    ,"Posts"."publishDate" AS "Posts.publishDate"
    ,"Posts"."publishedAt" AS "Posts.publishedAt"
    ,"Posts"."thumbnailUrl" AS "Posts.thumbnailUrl"
    ,"Posts"."imageUrl" AS "Posts.imageUrl"
    ,"Posts"."media" AS "Posts.media"
    ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."id" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.id"
    ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."slug" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.slug"
    ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."title" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.title"
    ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."subtitle" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.subtitle"
    ,"Posts.PostTranslations"."language" AS "Posts.PostTranslations.language"
FROM "Series" AS "Series"
INNER JOIN "SeriesTranslations" AS "SeriesTranslations" ON "Series"."id" = "SeriesTranslations"."SeriesId"
    AND "SeriesTranslations"."language" IN ('en-us')
    AND "SeriesTranslations"."slug" = 'sdf'
LEFT JOIN "Posts" AS "Posts" ON "Series"."id" = "Posts"."SeriesId"
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM "PostTranslations" AS pt
        WHERE pt.LANGUAGE IN ('en-us')
            AND pt."PostId" = "Posts"."id" LIMIT 1
        )
LEFT JOIN "PostTranslations" AS "Posts.PostTranslations" ON "Posts"."id" = "Posts.PostTranslations"."PostId"
    AND "Posts.PostTranslations"."language" IN ('en-us')
WHERE (1 = 1)
ORDER BY "Posts"."publishDate" DESC
    ,"Posts"."id" DESC;
```

And here is new query plan:

```
                                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=1014671.76..1014671.76 rows=1 width=695) (actual time=2140.906..2140.908 rows=14 loops=1)
   Sort Key: "Posts"."publishDate", "Posts".id
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 45kB
   ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.03..1014671.76 rows=1 width=695) (actual time=85.862..2140.745 rows=14 loops=1)
         Join Filter: ("Posts".id = "Posts.PostTranslations"."PostId")
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 28266
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.03..1014165.24 rows=1 width=564) (actual time=85.307..2042.304 rows=14 loops=1)
               Join Filter: ("Series".id = "SeriesTranslations"."SeriesId")
               Rows Removed by Join Filter: 35
               ->  Index Scan using "SeriesTranslations-slug-language-unique" on "SeriesTranslations"  (cost=0.03..4.03 rows=1 width=200) (actual time=0.044..0.046 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((slug = 'in-residence-architecture-design-video-series'::text) AND (language = 'en-us'::text))
               ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..1014159.63 rows=450 width=368) (actual time=85.243..2042.207 rows=49 loops=1)
                     Join Filter: ("Series".id = "Posts"."SeriesId")
                     Rows Removed by Join Filter: 18131
                     ->  Seq Scan on "Series"  (cost=0.00..11.35 rows=450 width=100) (actual time=0.006..0.046 rows=9 loops=1)
                     ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1012330.79 rows=1010 width=272) (actual time=4.422..226.499 rows=2020 loops=9)
                           ->  Seq Scan on "Posts"  (cost=0.00..1012329.78 rows=1010 width=272) (actual time=39.785..2020.448 rows=2020 loops=1)
                                 Filter: (SubPlan 1)
                                 SubPlan 1
                                   ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..500.94 rows=1 width=1267) (actual time=0.995..0.995 rows=1 loops=2020)
                                         ->  Seq Scan on "PostTranslations" pt  (cost=0.00..500.94 rows=1 width=1267) (actual time=0.992..0.992 rows=1 loops=2020)
                                               Filter: ((language = 'en-us'::text) AND ("PostId" = "Posts".id))
                                               Rows Removed by Filter: 1591
         ->  Seq Scan on "PostTranslations" "Posts.PostTranslations"  (cost=0.00..499.44 rows=2020 width=135) (actual time=0.003..3.188 rows=2020 loops=14)
               Filter: (language = 'en-us'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 964
 Total runtime: 2141.432 ms
(27 rows)
```

Comment: That is not a simple query, have you run it with explain? Do you have indexes?

Comment: I edited my question with explain result and indexes I have.

Comment: `LIMIT 1` in a `EXISTS( ...)` subquery is completely useless.

Comment: Please post the execution plan as formatted text, or even better upload it to http://explain.depesz.com the screenshot is really hard to read.

Comment: There is no need to check the existence of matches`WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "SeriesTranslations" AS t ...` if the same table is joined anyway:: `INNER JOIN "SeriesTranslations" AS "SeriesTranslations" ...`

Comment: wildplasser: you are right, however I cant do inner join because of ORM limitation right now. I will check if this is a cause though. I added link to explain in my question (http://explain.depesz.com/s/fhm)

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to get the actual rowcounts and timings as well as the expected ones.

Comment: I updated latest query plany with the one with ANALYZE option.

Comment: Is `"Posts"."id"` a PRIMARY KEY ? Do you have valid statistics (expecteds are a bit off ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An index on the FKs might help the JOINs:

```
CREATE INDEX ON PostTranslations (PostId); -- For FK
VACUUM ANALYZE  PostTranslations ; -- refresh statistics

CREATE INDEX ON SeriesTranslations (SeriesId ); -- FK
VACUUM ANALYZE SeriesTranslations ;

CREATE INDEX ON Posts (SeriesId) ; -- FK
VACUUM ANALYZE Posts ;
```

And **REMOVE** the `LIMIT 1` from the `EXISTS(...)` subqueries. They can only do harm.

Comment: I thought that indexes are automatically create on foreign keys?? I always used limit 1 in exists (sometimes I am querying for more rows than one actually) - does it really matter if there is LIMIT or not?

Comment: No, the *target* for an FK needs to have *at least* an UNIQUE constraint. The (*source*) FK itself does not *need* to have an index. (but it helps) The `LIMIT 1` is completely clueless (mysql-ism?) in an `EXISTS(...)` subquery: Either it exists or it doesn't.

Comment: It speeded up query by 50%, but still its too slow I think. Maybe I should add index on "PostTranslations" (language, PostId)?

Comment: Also, according to limit 1 in exists - for example when SELECT inside EXISTS matches 100k rows then it wont be faster when I add LIMIT 1? I thought then only first of those 100k matching will be returned and it will be faster.

Comment: Ah sory, in fact it speeded up query to 250ms (from 1.5s)(the time in fact is a time of response from API not direct query time so now it is very fast - THANKS!)

Comment: `I thought then only first of those 100k matching will be returned` Don't think, measure. `EXISTS (...)` queries are different: the optimiser **knows** that `true` can be returned once the first matching tuple is found.